# Express.js: Empty object sent along with response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have three prepared SQL statements that I want to execute. Once the SQL statement is executed, the results are added to a response object, and then sent to the client. The response then shows an empty object even though it should be there. I might be wrong but I think my response may not be in the correct place. Any other suggestions are welcome as I'm still new to Node.js.

```
    const s1 = 'small sql statement'

    const s2 = 'small sql statement'

    const s3 = 'small sql statement'

    var responseObject = {}

    const onError = err => {res.send({error: err}); console.error(err)}
    const updateResponse = results => {results.map((item) => {Object.assign(responseObject, item)})}
    const statements = [s1, s2, s3]

    router.get('/stats', (req,res,next) => {
        statements.map((statement) => {
            con.query(statement, (err,results) => {
                if (err) onError(err);
                 updateResponse(results);
            })
        })
        res.send({
            success: responseObject
        })
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: because res.send dont wait for  con.query result.
you can use async and await for do this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the response before your database queries have completed.

You can use promises to handle this:

```
const s1 = 'small sql statement'

const s2 = 'small sql statement'

const s3 = 'small sql statement'

const statements = [s1, s2, s3]

router.get('/stats', (req, res, next) => {

  // Generate array of promises
  const promises = statements.map(statement => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      con.query(statement, (err, results) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(results);
      });

    });
  });

  // Wait for all promises to resolve
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {

      // Merge results into single object
      const responseObject = results
        .flat()
        .reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {});

      res.send({ success: responseObject });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({ error: err });
      console.error(err);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

---

If your version of Node does not support `.flat()` then you can amend to this:

```
const responseObject = [].concat.apply([], results)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing a database query is an asynchronous task. You are sending response even before queries are done executing which as you have declared is empty. You can use async/await or promise to execute asynchronously and wait for data then append data to responseObject.